# $(f_n)$ integrable sequence of functions that converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, sequence-of-function

I'm reading Abbot's Understanding Analysis, and have stumbled across this problem, but there is a step that I don't fully understand.

---

The problem is:

Assume that for each $n$, $f_n$ is an (Riemann) integrable function on $[a, b]$. If $(f_n) \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a, b]$, prove that $f$ is also integrable on this set.

---

Solution:

$$U(f, P) - L(f, P)$$$$=U(f, P) - U(f_N, P) + U(f_N, P) - L(f_N, P) + L(f_N, P) - L(f, P)$$$$\leq |U(f, P) - U(f_N, P)| + (U(f_N, P) - L(f_N, P)) + |L(f_N, P) - L(f, P)|$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Because $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, we can choose $N$ so that:

$|f_N(x) - f(x)| \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{3(b-a)}$ for all $x \in [a, b]$

Now the function $f_N$ is integrable and so there exists a partition $P$ for which

$U(f_N, P) - L(f_N, P) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$

Let's consider a particular subinterval $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ from this partition. If

$M_k = \sup\{f(x): x \in [x_{k -1}, x_k]\}$ and $N_k = \sup\{f_N(x): x \in [x_{k -1}, x_k]\}$

then our choice of f_N guarantees that

$|M_k - N_k| \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{3 (b  - a)}$

The proof goes on and it demonstrates that:

$U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon /  3 + \epsilon /  3 + \epsilon /  3$

---

My doubt is why is it so that

$|M_k - N_k| \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{3 (b - a)}$

We have that

$|f_N(x) - f(x)| \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{3(b-a)}$ for all $x \in [a, b]$

But this only work for the same $x$. The supremums can have different $x$ value, or they may even not have a $x$ value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M_k-N_k>\frac{\epsilon}{3(b-a)}$ would imply $f(x)-N_k>\frac{\epsilon}{3(b-a)}$ for some $x$, and this would imply $f_N(x)>N_k$.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the inequality as $$f(x) - \frac{\epsilon} {3(b-a)}<f_N(x)<f(x)+\frac{\epsilon} {3(b-a)}$$ and take supremum as $x$ varies in interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ to get $$M_{k} - \frac{\epsilon} {3(b-a)}\leq N_k\leq M_k+\frac{\epsilon} {3(b-a)}$$ and this simply means that $$|M_k-N_k|\leq \frac{\epsilon} {3(b-a)}$$